# sqlite3 installed location for ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get started with ruby on rails and whenever I try to start the server using rails server command I get the sqlite3 not found error. I tried the following:

```
which sqlite3
```

And I got the following:

```
/opt/local/bin/sqlite3
```

I am thinking that should it not be

```
/usr/local/bin/sqlite3
```

Why is it installed incorrectly on my machine? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you give more info on how did you install sqlite3 before? Knowing your distro may help too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble Getting the Rails Server Started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217602/trouble-getting-the-rails-server-started)

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of `gem list`. If the **sqlite** gem is not in there then you need to install it.

For Rails 3 you need to add the following in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sqlite'
```

... then run:

```
bundle install
```

For Rails 2 run:

```
gem install sqlite
```

Comment: Just a note, in his question about mongo mapper, he says that he is not using bundler. Would that affect anything?