# Rails with Mongo Mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

This is turning out to be the worst day for learning rails. Already failed to connect and configure to sqlite3, mysql databases I turned to mongo mapper and facing the same issues. When I try to start the rails server I get the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- mongo_mapper (LoadError)
```

I have already installed mongo_mapper gem but when I do 'which mongo_mapper' it does not return anything.

Here is my mongo_config.rb file placed inside the initializers folder:

```
require "rubygems"
require "mongo_mapper"

MongoMapper.database = "blog-#{Rails.env}"
```

UPDATE 1:

I changed to the following:

```
require "rubygems"
include MongoMapper

MongoMapper.database = "blog-#{Rails.env}"
```

And now I get the following error:

```
   /Users/azamsharp/Projects/railsprojects/blog/config/initializers/mongo_config.rb:2: uninitialized constant MongoMapper (NameError)
```

Comment: Instead of giving up on sqlite3 and mysql why dont you give those a try again. They are the simplest of databases and NoSQL just adds more complexity to the mix. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I have been trying to get the rails server to start for the last 5 hours and still no success. I am using Rails 3.0.7. Here is the thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217602/trouble-getting-the-rails-server-started

Comment: Yagooar's answer below solved my problem, don't you want to accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 4):

**You must use bundler with rails 3**. don't try to not use it. add the following to your Gemfile

```
source 'http://gemcutter.org'
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem "rails", "3.0.7"
gem 'bson', "1.1.1"
gem 'bson_ext', "1.1.1"
gem 'mongo_mapper'
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

then `rails server` will work

Answer (score 4):

In order to get mongo_mapper working in Rails (tested under Rails 3.1, should work in Rails 3.0.x as well), you have to follow these steps:

1. In Gemfile, add the mongo_mapper and bson gem:

   ```
   gem 'mongo_mapper'
   gem 'bson_ext'
   ```
2. Run bundle install
3. In the config/ directory, create a mongo.yml file like this one:

   ```
   # config/mongo.yml

   defaults: &defaults
     host: 127.0.0.1
     port: 27017

   development:
     <<: *defaults
     database: db_development
     username: user
     password: password

   test:
     <<: *defaults
     database: db_test

   # set these environment variables on your prod server
   production:
     <<: *defaults
     database:
     username:
     password:
   ```
4. In the config/initializers directory, create a mongo.rb file like this:

   ```
    # config/initializers/mongo.rb

    #include MongoMapper

    db_config = YAML::load(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "/config/mongo.yml")))
    #
    if db_config[Rails.env] && db_config[Rails.env]['adapter'] == 'mongodb'
      mongo = db_config[Rails.env]
      MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new(mongo['host'] || 'localhost',
                                                 mongo['port'] || 27017,
                                                :logger => Rails.logger)
      MongoMapper.database = mongo['database']

      if mongo['username'] && mongo['password']
        MongoMapper.database.authenticate(mongo['username'], mongo['password'])
      end
    end

    # Used for image uploads
    # CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    #   mongo = db_config[Rails.env]
    #   config.grid_fs_database = mongo['database']
    #   config.grid_fs_host = mongo['host'] || 'localhost'
    #   config.grid_fs_access_url = "gridfs"
    #   config.grid_fs_username = mongo['username']
    #   config.grid_fs_password =  mongo['password']
    # end

    # It's also possible to define indexes in the the model itself; however,
    # a few issues are being worked out still. This is a temporary solution.
    # Comment.ensure_index([["story_id", 1], ["path", 1], ["points", -1]])
    # MongoMapper.ensure_indexes!

    # Handle passenger forking.
    # if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
    #    PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    #      MongoMapper.database.connect_to_master if forked
    #    end
    # end

    if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
       PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
         MongoMapper.connection.connect if forked
       end
    end
   ```
5. Start the mongod server before starting the rails server and enjoy!

Comment: +1 Nice one. But is it me, or is the `mongo.yml` configuration missing an `adapter: mongodb` configuration? I put it under `defaults:`, personally.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the require lines and replace them with `include MongoMapper`

Comment: I am not using bundle install I installed the mongo_mapper gem manually using sudo gem install mongo_mapper.

Comment: Why are you not using bundler?