# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension when installing Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite3-ruby

I am trying to start up my first rails project. Im on Mac OS X 10.6.7, have Xcode4 installed, ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.1

When I type bundle install I get this error:

```
~/rails_project/first_app$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.1)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.4.2)
Using activemodel (3.0.1)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.3)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.28)
Using actionpack (3.0.1)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.1)
Using treetop (1.4.9)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.1)
Using arel (1.0.1)
Using activerecord (3.0.1)
Using activeresource (3.0.1)
Using bundler (1.0.14)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.1)
Using rails (3.0.1)
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

       /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
/Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:853:in `block in find_header'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:852:in `find_header'
       from extconf.rb:28:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:511:in `block in build_extensions'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `each'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `build_extensions'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:159:in `install'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `block in install'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in run'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `block in run'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.14/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
       from /Users/tiffany/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
~/rails_project/first_app$
```

All the info I have found for this error online has been specific to Windows or Linux machines. In one of my google searches I saw somewhere that it might be a linking issue, that the attempt to verify the development tools failed. Can anyone help with this issue? I also tried doing gem install sqlite3-ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/lib and that didn't work either. HELP! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install sqlite3, the gem needs the sqlite header files to link against.  See [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143776/install-sqlite3-on-mac-osx)

You can install it with macports: `sudo port install sqlite3`.

Or if you are using brew try `brew install sqlite`.

Comment: For Debian / Ubuntu, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458602/sqlite3-ruby-install-error-on-ubuntu