# rails connect to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to open by my rails console in my newsly created app, but I can't connect to a database.  It looks like there might be a problem with sqlite3-1.3.3 vs 1.3.4

```
$ rails c
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `establish_connection': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.4, runtime), already activated sqlite3-1.3.3. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
```

Install

```
$sudo gem install 
ERROR:  could not find gem activerecord-sqlite3-adapter locally or in a repository
```

What gems I have installed

```
$gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.2.5)
```

I'm using rails 3.1.1

EDIT:

Here is my gemfile
    source 'http://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Running bundle install produces this
    $sudo bundle install
    using rake (0.9.2.2) 
    ...
    Using sqlite3 (1.3.3) 
    Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

```
$ bundle show sqlite3
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3
```

Comment: What does your `Gemfile` contain (not `Gemfile.lock`)?

Comment: What does `bundle exec rails c` output?

Answer (score 1):

You're using Rails 3.1, which uses bundler to manage gems.

1. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile
2. run `bundle` form the command line

This will install the gems your app needs. You should then be able to launch the console.

Comment: Didn't work :/  I added it to my gemfile and ran bundle.  I still get the same error.

Comment: What if you also add `gem 'sqlite3-rails'` to your bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar situations in the past because of missing/bad shared libraries.  Gems install ruby code, native bindings to libraries, but they do not install the external libraries themselves.

The dependency for sqlite on Ubuntu, for example, is libsqlite3-dev.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

For OSX:

[Install sqlite3 on mac osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143776/install-sqlite3-on-mac-osx)